# Cheapo Enigma machine (Robbers)

Tags: permutations, cops-and-robbers

For cops' post, [Cheapo Enigma machine (Cops)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117318/cheapo-enigma-machine-cops)

A robber's submission consists of a program/function that accepts the output of a cop's code and returns the input for all the outputs provided by that cop's code. (In other words, you must write the inverse function)

You cannot use built-ins that have the sole purpose of hashing or encryption.

## Input/Output format

8 bits (0 or 1), or a base-10 integer in range 1-256, 0-255 or -128 to 127. Can use standard I/O or file I/O. Function can also return a value as output. Input and output must belong to the same range (as in, binary, 1-256, 0-255 or -128 to 127), which must also be the same range as that used by the cop.

## Scoring

Ratio of the cop's byte count to your byte count. Highest score wins.

You can submit a robber attempt against your own cop code for reference. (Of course this code isn't eligible for winning)

## Notification

Please edit the corresponding cop's answer to include your new byte count and the corresponding ratio.

Comment: At first I was wondering how you were going to make Emigna into a machine. Then I realized you weren't talking about the user.

Comment: OK, sorry for bothering you again, but I want to make sure I got it right this time. If the brainfuck answer reads and prints bytes (code points 0 to 255) and my Jelly answer takes an integer between 0 and 255 and returns an integer in the same range, is that acceptable?

Comment: @Dennis No, it isn't. Maybe you (or someone else) could suggest an alternate wording that makes this clearer.

Comment: @carusocomputing Emigna is a machine, right? He has every single 05AB1E program loaded up in his memory system, yeah?

Answer (score 3):

### [JavaScript by Christoph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117414/58563), 8/25

```js
f=(y,x=0)=>y?f(y/2,x^y):x
```

(range 0-255)

Sadly, `f=(y,x)=>y?f(y/2,x^y):x` works for all values except `0`.

#### Technical note

We use `y/2` rather than `y>>1` to save a byte. This is abusing the fact that any value of `y` will eventually be rounded to `0` because of [arithmetic underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

Answer (score 2):

### [JavaScript by fəˈnɛtɪk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117364/58563), 13/19

```js
x=>((514>>x%2)-x)/2
```

(range 1-256)

Answer (score 2):

## [C, by Dave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117487/41127), 64/<s>95</s> <s>92</s> 85

```
b,i,e,t[256];r(x){for(;!b;++i,b=e==x)for(srand(i&&e);t[e=rand()%256]++;);return i-1;}
```

[Try it here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#jVBBboMwEDyHV2yQguziKCRVe9n6F9xoD6AskiVwKmMq1Ii307Uhx0iVjFcznpkdsTTKKFK@ury9f6ETk7y3Nydw32CeG9Vo0nqSgRpcba/CZBlJ9BXpCOUh@PIcJTryo7Ngjmecl3LNa0PeapyyjNHxLCXGBWU1PYuYcE4SYz30tbFCwj3ZBUtgrC7QwgewBSHPbXzcRS1oaIWVuOGRsRM940C0grGGTb87nb4di1qR/tSducKheL2CCLdkW5ifNlVgFfQKxpjJHnA0kAfuApYmD54GH1566pkXXkGhQrOXwfzSrQ2F5erdFOVzRcN7CwSzDoqD@Zk/6gZaaz9KGxtr7//Ve/up5y2OzyOm7jpYg9Ig3YS8d17@AA)!

## C, shorter version, 64/<s>89</s> 71

```
i,e,t[256];r(x){for(srand(1);t[e=rand()%256]++||++i,e!=x;);return i-1;}
```

This one is more implementation specific, but works on TIO. 
Same length as the PHP solution, I wasn't able to get it any shorter than this.

[Try it here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#jZBRa4MwFIWf66@4FVqSJaW6sb3c@S98c3sQjBDQdMQ4wlp/u7uJKWMPg4GanJtzvhxctVTSNY/PL@9omefX/mLZZFvTsZKja1QV9/wQHELcbkJQYl955GiVm60BfSpxWeuN0QfGlvfHI6lTyTkGKNaN/w37QXhcskwbB2OrDeNwzXYhEiamKtDAK1AEQQgTD3fRCxX0zHBMeiZt2Ug6DHpGuoLk353PH5ZMPcs/20F3cCieOmDhyykW1jeTSzASRglzZFIGrJqUA@oCRnkHTk0unIxqpDlzEgoZmj1M@ktd@lCYb9nkqP92aLq3QFBxocFCrxomtfW9t9Um9t3/q3D6m2XC0XPHtMMAGygP1mSke5f1Gw)!

Comment: Ok I will take it up with the cops submission then.  Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Javascript by histocrat, 27 / 29](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117498/29637)

```
x=>x-65?x-126?x*127%258:131:6
```

Sadly two hard codings are needed in order to break it. <strike>Note that the orginal function doesn't map any value to *130* but maps a value to *256*.</strike>

Comment: Having 256 in the range is legal according to the rules ("8 bits (0 or 1), or a base-10 integer in range 1-256"). This is still a valid Robber on that range, though!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript by fəˈnɛtɪk, 13 / 12](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117364/58563)

```
x=>x*128%257
```

Another multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117581/64505), 11/13

```javascript
x=>a.sort().indexOf(x)
for(a=[],i=0;i<256;)a[i]=i++;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#XZCxbsMgEIbn81NETBAiK7g1TeUSqU3btUPUyfFgERxhpQZhD5aaPLsLtiulHZA4fcd3/1GJoRfbMm6N6zCJdXNU/UeFexJVxuFS5MVKi3Wmn5KUZ6TMdSE0pdkQqPxH5S@NpJDxV2lxRSJpmtacVXw2J4wOB1gDgwTu4B5S4PAAG3iEZ3iBHbzCG7yjafBkZTzzOvIdLRZW6CXj48XGndl3TjcnzDjxxae1yu3KVmFCESDfFBS1V9RBUc8K/5YKmTO@1LQu5s6rP7cRLYmuY/zpQ27CJGk6p9EVHlf1Mk1ZcbmEaus5@bOscs44tArQS4cf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [22/3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117581/53748) = 7 1/3

```
⁹ḶDÞḊi
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#XZQ9bhNBGIZ7TrF0KVZo3/kf6nAKRGFFC0QKicjafRIhRYIrACegBSWCCp/EexHzPV86pHjknTwzO@/P@LjePh4efp3uvx8ePp8fn57@/tzfr3c/nu3vD4@f1ts/h99f1puvrz7uNhfLsH0/D5vrd7sP8@V2HJbd2dm8LM/t/6dX8zJcXm2HGfA/7u3m/GJ3Pb8YXp6sN9@Ox9fTOMj@FGyo3YZuM2GyucBcCNGGmGxI2QYDmLDnaI@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@QjAhIJqXi1gIv/CAATk8hJ1X98gGt68w8)**

The [cop submission by fəˈnɛtɪk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117581/53748) was to return the **n<sup>th</sup>** (**0**-indexed) lexicographically sorted decimal number using the domain **[0,255]**.

I first literally reversed the operation described, `⁹ḶDÞi⁸‘` - takes the lowered range of **256**, `⁹Ḷ`, and `Þ` instructs to sort it by a key function of conversion to a decimal list, `D`; then finds the index of, `i`, the input, `⁸`, and subtracts **1**, `‘` (Jelly lists are **1**-indexed).

Then I golfed it by dequeuing the sorted list with `Ḋ`. When an item is not found `i` returns **0** as required for the removed first element (**0**), while everything else is found one index earlier, allowing the removal of the decrement, `‘`, which in turn gives `i` implicit input on its right from the left (only) input to the monadic link.

Answer (score 1):

## [Javascript by Magenta, 32 / 23](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117676/29637)

```
x=>x%16*16+(x/16+13)%16
```

Code basically switches the lower and the upper 4 bits and does a modulo addition on one part.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP, Score 64/71](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117487/29637)

```
for(srand(0);$a<256;)$b[$c=rand()%256]++||$d[$c]=$a++;echo$d[$argn]|0;
```

Luckily PHP's `rand` just forwards to the **stdlib** like C. So this works as long as we're using the same stdlib. This means it works on *TIO* but not on e.g. *sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com*. The current version of Dave's code just iterates over a pseudorandom sequence and returns the *nth unique value* so I guess there might be much shorter answers if a golfing languages also uses the stdlib.

[Here's an implementation](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1Q1oYICTBM4zBz04) of Dave's code that does not dependent on the stdlib. That might also help.

Comment: +1 for finding a way to switch language on this one! Any idea why this doesn't need to `srand(1)`? Also here's a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HYxBDsIgEEX3noI005TJGENN2s2UeBBlga21bGiDS/HsCCz/y/tvuh3bkdY9yE@wfpEKGex0HUZGeN5h1pVim4khihGWDI0GS8SvedvLtuHtTVScChDNwzd8KkVwWjG4WgNHhN8qyPJx@YDiIrpzx27NatuPWvcDFqUmfukP "PHP – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Dave `srand(x&&f(x-1))` this stops only if `x==0` therefore it gets seeded with `0` on the first round. Not sure why the next calls don't change it.

Comment: @Dave it seems  `srand(0)` breaks `rand` (see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qScKrrA9cLNZyet8)). I guess `srand(0)` automatically gets promoted to `srand(1)`. I guess if you could use a different seed each time it would get a lot harder to break it.

Comment: Interesting that this works. Seems to be specific to the stdlib version used on TIO, the behaviour in C on there is apparently the same, while on my local machine with clang it requires to re-invoke srand with 0 resp. 1 on each iteration, instead of just invoking it once with 0.

Comment: @Appleshell seems Christoph's suspicions are correct: glibc has a special check. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8049852/1180785 (since you mention clang, I'm guessing your local is OSX, so no glibc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [16/18](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117417/24877)

```matlab
@(x)mod(x*171,256)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7N10KjQzM1P0ajQMtYxMjXT/I8QMDQ3hAgl5hVrpGkYWBmZmmpq2tqCGf8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [2/5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117485/12012)

```
^H$7¡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARoA5f//XkgkN8Kh/@KBueG4tsK1XkjCtcW8w4dH/w) to see the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [8/5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117414/12012)

```
^H$7¡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARoA5f//XkgkN8Kh/@KBueG4tsK1XkjCtcW8w4dH/w) to see the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [16/6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117417/12012)

```
×171%⁹
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394uqG5oeqjxp3/jUzNHu7Ydmjr4enGqkD2oa1H9xxud/8PAA) to see the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [11/8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117490/12012)

```
*205%257
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@69lZGCqamRq/t/I1Czo0FYtMOfQ1qN7Dre7/wcA) to see the whole table.

In case robber submissions in a different languages are disallowed in the future, I call dibs on the following solution.

```javascript
g=(x,y=0)=>x-++y**5%257?g(x,y):y
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [37/11](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117812/12012)

```
O_77×191%⁹Ọ
```

Uses the same I/O format as the cop. Not sure if that is required.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@8fb25@eLqhpaHqo8adD3f3/P//3wcA) to see the whole table.

#### How it works

For input **n**, the cop answer computes **f(n) := ((((n + 5) % 256 × 2) % 256 + 2) % 256 × 9) % 256**. Since `%` is a linear operator, this is equivalent to **f(n) = (((n + 5) × 7 + 2) × 9) % 256**. Expanding the right term, we get **f(n) = (63n + 333) % 256 = (63n + 77) % 256**.

Reversing this is rather straightforward. To undo the addition, we simply have to subtract **77**. Also, since **191 × 63 % 256 = 12033 % 256 = 1**, it follows that **191** is **63**'s inverse modulo **256**, so multiplying by **191** undoes multiplying by **63**. This way, **g(n) = (n - 77) × 191 % 256** defines the inverse of **f**.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [35/7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117745/12012)

```
⁹Ṗ+\%⁹i
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocefDndO0Y1SBjMz/BkVGpqaHth6erq1qamhkZXRo69E9h9sfNa1x/w8A) to see the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc) by Bijan, 32 / 30](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117789/29637)

```
g(x){x=x?g(--x)*205+51&255:0;}
```

Had a fun time golfing it, thanks ! `x=` allows to skip return with gcc and tcc (you might want to change your answer to include it). `g(--x)*205+51&255` is the inverse.